# Decoding Json with Circe when fields are incomplete

Tags: scala, circe, argonaut

I have a transcript in json format with a bunch of words in it

```
{
     "words": [{
          "duration": 123,
          "name": "world"
          "time": 234,
          "speaker": null
      }]
}
```

I have been using Circe to encode/decode Json. In this particular case:

```
import io.circe.generic.auto._
import io.circe.parser._

val decoded = decode[Transcript](transcriptJson)
```

And my ADT look like:

```
case class Word(
  duration: Double,
  name: String,
  time: Float,
  para: String,
  speaker: Option[String],
  key: Option[String] = None,
  strike: Option[String] = None,
  highlight: Option[String] = None
)

case class Transcript(words: List[Word])
```

Sometimes words have keys like "strike" or "highlight", but most likely not. When it doesn't, I get the following error message.

```
Left(DecodingFailure([A]List[A], List(DownField(highlight), MoveRight, MoveRight, MoveRight, MoveRight, MoveRight, MoveRight, MoveRight, MoveRight, MoveRight, MoveRight, MoveRight, MoveRight, MoveRight, MoveRight, MoveRight, MoveRight, MoveRight, MoveRight, MoveRight, MoveRight, MoveRight, MoveRight, MoveRight, MoveRight, MoveRight, MoveRight, MoveRight, MoveRight, MoveRight, MoveRight, MoveRight, MoveRight, MoveRight, DownArray, DownField(words))))
```

What would be the best way to decode it properly when a "word" doesn't have all the fields?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As Travis Brown pointed out on Gitter:

"this would work as-is with generic-extras:"

```
import io.circe.generic.extras.Configuration

implicit val config: Configuration = Configuration.default.withDefaults
```

(plus a default value for para and `import io.circe.generic.extras.auto._`)

Comment: as Travis Brown on Gitter also points out: `circe-generic-extras` is nowadays in its own repository and uses a slightly different versioning scheme than the rest of circe. For instance right now there is a `"io.circe" %% "circe-generic" % "0.12.3"` but only a `"io.circe" %% "circe-generic-extras" % "0.12.2"`