# How to decode missing json array as empty List with circe

Tags: json, scala, circe

For example, we have some case class

```scala
case class Foo(a: Int, b: List[String])
```

And we want to deserialize instance of `Foo` from json `{"a": 1}` replacing missing `b` array with `Nil`

We can create custom decoder for such behavior

```scala
implicit val fooDecoder: Decoder[Foo] = (c: HCursor) => 
  for {
    a <- c.downField("a").as[Int]
    b <- c.downField("b").as[Option[List[String]]
  } yield Foo(a, b.getOrElse(Nil))
```

But, unfortunately, the created this way decoder doesn't accumulate all decoding failures.

Is there any way to create decoder with failures accumulation or any way to replace standard list deserialization behavior in circe?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try providing [default](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46475269/5205022) value `b: List[String] = Nil` using `circe-generic-extras` like so

```
import io.circe.parser._
import io.circe.generic.extras.Configuration
import io.circe.generic.extras.auto._

implicit val config: Configuration = Configuration.default.withDefaults
case class Foo(a: Int, b: List[String] = Nil)
val raw = """{"a": 1}"""
decode[Foo](raw) // res0: Either[io.circe.Error,Foo] = Right(Foo(1,List()))
```

where

```
libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
  "io.circe" %% "circe-core" % "0.12.0-M3",
  "io.circe" %% "circe-parser" % "0.12.0-M3",
  "io.circe" %% "circe-generic-extras" % "0.12.0-M3",
  "io.circe" %% "circe-generic" % "0.12.0-M3"
)
```

Comment: FYI: It moved to https://github.com/circe/circe-generic-extras

Answer (score 1):

You can also use `.map(_.getOrElse(List.empty))` as well

```
implicit val fooDecoder: Decoder[Foo] = (c: HCursor) => 
  for {
    a <- c.downField("a").as[Int]
    b <- c.downField("b").as[Option[List[String]].map(_.getOrElse(List.empty))
  } yield Foo(a, b)
```